# Can custom webhook in Parse send push notification to ios app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am working with an api which has a webhook with a callback url, such that when a certain event occurs, it uses an HTTP POST request with whatever URL I want. Can a Parse webhook be used, such that the POST request URL can talk to Parse and tell it to send a push notification to a particular iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. You can define a custom route that accepts POST data and then sends push (or does any other Parse functions.)

Custom Webhooks on Parse Cloud Code: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks

Full Cloud Code guide: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code